# What is the differece between a large loop antenna and a small loop antenna in terms of their response to an electromagnetic wave?

Tags: antenna, antenna-theory, loop-antenna, magnetic-loop

There is something that I don't get. I read that a small loop antenna (also called magnetic loop) responds more to the magnetic field than a large loop antenna does. I was wondering why this is the case and how does the electric field from a electromagnetic wave interact on a large loop antenna differently?

Comment: In term of RF EM far field, no diff E vs M, or the only difference is in gain or efficiency and pattern, which varys with antenna geometry.  In term of very near field, you get more current by passing a magnet thru many small turns of a inductor, than a single large turn.  Thus the (mis?)naming.